# Check if list exists in SharePoint Online without exception using CSOM

Tags: c#, sharepoint-online, csom

I am trying to delete a list in SharePoint Online by using the list title. But before that, I need to check if the list exists or not. I can use the method `SharepointContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(title)`, but this throws an exception if the list does not exist. It does not return null. I don't want the execution to error out and throw an exception. Also, I don't want to use try-catch as that will result in a lot of try-catch blocks.
The second option I have is to do a query `SharepointContext.LoadQuery(SharepointContext.Web.Lists.Where(list => list.Title == title))`
and then execute the query and search collection for lists in there. But this results in an error that I cannot use the `TItle` expression in the query.

Does anyone know a good way to check if a list exists in SharePoint online and not throw exceptions if it does not?

```
  public async Task<List> Get(Query query)
  {
      var library = SharepointContext.LoadQuery(
          SharepointContext.Web.Lists
              .Include(l => l.Title, l => l.Id)
              .Where(l => l.Title == query.Title));

      await SharepointContext.ExecuteQueryAsync();
      return library;
  }
```

**NOTE:**

- I do not want to use the PnP library
- I do not want to directly delete, I want to check before deletion
- I do not want to load titles of all the lists and then do an in-memory comparison

Comment: What exactly is 'title' in your context? property, field, etc.?

Comment: Its a property of the list same as Id

Comment: Is 'title" passed as a parameter of your method? If you try to specify the list name in Where clause it should work. SharepointContext.LoadQuery(SharepointContext.Web.Lists.Where(list => list.Title == "listName"))

Comment: Yes, the title is passed as a parameter. But it does not work.

Comment: @user2250152 Thanks, your comment gave me a direction. I found the solution, updating the answer for others to refer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the way the comparison is being done in the query. For some reason, the Where query is unable to decipher the term `query.Title`. For some reason, it was unable to directly refer to the property inside of the query parameter passed to the method. But after we hold the value in a local variable and use that in the query, it works fine.

```
public async Task<List> Get(Query query)
{
    var title = query.Title;

    var library = SharepointContext.LoadQuery(
        SharepointContext.Web.Lists
            .Include(l => l.Title, l => l.Id)
            .Where(l => l.Title == query.Title));

    await SharepointContext.ExecuteQueryAsync();
    return library;
}
```

The important bit here is `var title = query.Title;`